# Python script executes another script and resumes after second script completes its job

Tags: python, timeout, subprocess, wait

Is there a way to check if a subprocess has finished its job? My python script executes an 123.exe from cmd. 123.exe then does some things and in the end it writes 1 or 0 to a txt file. Python script then reads the txt file and continues with the job if '1' and stops if '0'. At the moment all that I can think of, is to put the python script to sleep for a minute. That way the 123.exe has most certainly written 1 or 0 into the txt file. This realization is very simple but at the same time stupid.

So my question is, is there a way to deal with this problem without the need for timeout? A way to make the python script to wait til the 123.exe stops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
retcode = subprocess.call(["123.exe"])
```

This will execute the command, wait until it finishes, and you get its return code into `retcode` (this way you could also avoid the need of checking the output status file, if the command returns a proper return code).

If you need to instantiate manually the `subprocess.Popen`, then go for

```
Popen.wait()
```

(and then check `Popen.returncode`).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the **[`call()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)** shorthand from the subprocess module. From the documentation:

> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete, then return
>   the returncode attribute.

It should work this way:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(["123.exe"])
```

of course you won't use the `retcode`, but your script will anyhow hang until the 123.exe has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p = subprocess(...)
os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)
```

This will wait until the process is done and your script will continue from here.

Comment: no need for using `os.waitpid()` since subprocess itself provides this functionality..

Comment: @redShadow You are right, using the subprocess for that is more sound.